# Handle touch of button residing in parent view controller, ios

Tags: ios

[image]

What would be the best way to handle user touch for the middle button? (UIImageView positioned over tab bar). The image/button is currently a property of the UITabBarController, which in turn contains two subview-controller pairs (Item #1 and #2). The user should navigate away from the tab bar controller upon touching this button (its not a tab).

Thanks! :)

Comment: Whats with the downvote?

Comment: Did you make your own subclass of UITabBarController?

Comment: Yes, subclassed UITabBarController and create/show the image in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an IBAction in your UITabBarController subclass. Whatever is supposed to happen when the button is tapped can be put there.

Comment: Thanks! I'll change the image view to an UIButton and try your suggestion :)

Comment: You don't have to change into a button. You could use a tap gesture recognizer as long as you enable user interactions for the view.